# How do I process the request in a controller after successful stateless authentication in Spring Security 5 & Spring Boot 2?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I'm trying to implement the following request flow:

1. GET request is sent to `/api/example` with authentication GET parameters
2. Parameters are parsed in a filter and a generated authentication object is sent for authentication
3. Provider successfully authenticates the object and returns it to the filter
4. Filter lets the request through to a controller mapped to `/api/example`
5. Controller returns the response

Points 1 to 3 are already implemented and working, the `successfulAuthentication` method gets called in the filter and there are no issues passing the request to an authentication success handler. I already ran into similar questions (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842162/how-to-make-spring-security-to-call-the-requested-resource-after-a-successful-au)) but most of them are outdated, use a lot of XML configuration and most importantly, the answers are not applicable to this use case (usually, some sort of cookie and/or token is expected to be passed both ways between the parties or a controller is not used).

The authentication parameters are mandatory and sent with every request, so there is zero need to remember any authentication states outside of the single request scope. The other party sending the GET request also does not need to be informed beyond sending a 401 or returning the expected response.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to achieve point 4 in the list above. Spring Security authentication success handler attempts to redirect by default which is undesirable as it either causes a infinite redirect loop (in case of redirect to `/api/example`) or invoking an entirely different part of the application (in case of the default `/`).

HTTP security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .anonymous().disable()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();

    http
        .antMatcher("/api/**")
        .addFilterBefore(this.apiAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated();
}
```

Relevant snippet from the authentication filter (extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`):

```
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
                                        Authentication authenticationResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationResult);

    if (this.eventPublisher != null) {
        eventPublisher.publishEvent(new InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent(authenticationResult, this.getClass()));
    }

    this.getSuccessHandler().onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authenticationResult);
}
```

There is also a custom `ApiAuthenticationProvider`, but it's working without any issues. I'd like to avoid any XML configuration and if possible, also redirects and cookies. Also keep in mind that there are multiple mappings to be authenticated with the same configuration (e.g. `/api/example`, `/api/sample`...).

Approaches I've already tried:

1. Redirecting to URL obtained from the request (causes an infinite redirect loop)
2. Leaving the `onAuthenticationSuccess` method of the `ApiAuthenticationSuccessHandler` empty (returns a blank page)
3. Continuing the filtering in the `successfulAuthentication` method of the filter (eventually causes a NullPointerException to be thrown)
4. Extending `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` and using `setUseReferer(true)` in the constructor (redirects to `/`)
5. Using `setDefaultTargetUrl` in the handler when extending `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` and passing URL from the request as an argument (causes an infinite redirect loop)

Comment: Where and how your controller is defined? Did you override the `DispatcherServlet` default config? It seems strange that your controller is not hit after the filters processing.

Comment: My controller is defined in a separate class, I've verified that it is working without authentication by disabling it and manually going to `/api/example`. So far, it is a very basic one just for testing purposes. It simply writes the URL to the response body. I did not override any configuration for the DispatcherServlet.

The issue seems to stem from the fact that Spring Security always wants to redirect somewhere, even though I just want it to act like a gateway to the controller.

Comment: @Sandwich If you don't want to redirect the request you could always forward the request to your controller. However, you are loosing authorization. All authenticated users with any role are forwarded.

Comment: @dur Thanks for the suggestion, I will try that (even though it is a bit of a hack). Thankfully, there are no roles to speak of in this use case. Losing authorisation should not be an issue.